# Disable initMethod for @Bean in test

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a test for a `@Configuration` class. It declares a `@Bean` with an `initMethod`:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "doSomething")
public MyBean myBean() {
    // instantiation and initialization
}
```

The `doSomething` method does a lot of work and would require a complex test setup to succeed. I want to test that the bean was initialized correctly but I don't want Spring to call the `doSomething` method once the initialization is done.

My first idea was to use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`:

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    String[] beanNames = beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(MyBean.class);
    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanNames[0]);
    // TODO: disable initMethod
}
```

But it seems there is no way to use `BeanDefinition` to disable the `initMethod`.

Am I missing something or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Why you don't want `doSomething` to be called?

Comment: The `doSomething` method does a lot of work and would require a complex test setup to succeed. I only want to test the initialization, not that the work is actually done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the `BeanDefinition` is a `RootBeanDefinition` (or `AbstractBeanDefinition`), then use its [`setInitMethodName`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition.html#setInitMethodName-java.lang.String-) to set the init method to `null`.

> Set the name of the initializer method. The default is `null` in which
>   case there is no initializer method.

```
if (beanDefinition instanceof RootBeanDefinition) {
    ((RootBeanDefinition) beanDefinition).setInitMethodName(null);
}
```